# git: Delete files that were moved to LFS from history but keep pointers using filter-repo

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-filter-repo

I have a very old and big repo that has a lot of large files.
Migration to LFS was done very late so the history still holds a lot of large files.
I am using filter-repo to do some history rewriting and need the best way to either:

1. Move also the files from the history to LFS
2. Delete all the old files before they moved to LFS

I tried using the --path-glob or --paths-from-file (for all lfs files) but that also deletes the pointers...
How can I achieve this?

Comment: For the 1st option, `git lfs migrate import` can rewrite the old commits and convert the large files to LFS.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks. This is less preferred as it takes a very long time (the repo is very big), filter-repo runs much faster but I haven't found a way to solve this with it

Comment: Have you considered importing *all* old binaries into LFS instead of deleting them? It sounds like only a tip migration was done, but `git lfs migrate --everything` has the ability to also convert all older commits.

Comment: @jessehouwing yes, it takes too long. Ran for over 36 house and didn't finish... I need a faster approach because work is halted while this is being done

Comment: How big a repo is this?! And are you sure your `.gitattributes` is correct in that case?  I ran this against a 34GB repo on my workstation and it finished in under 2 hours.

Comment: @jessehouwing it's 26GB. Yes, the .gitattributes is correct

Answer (score 0):

> Migration to LFS was done very late so the history still holds a lot of large files

That means you need to list those large files, and migrate them to LFS, without touching existing large files already migrated to LFS.

### list existing files already migrated to LFS:

Generate a list of files that are already tracked by Git LFS in your repository. You can use [`git lfs ls-files`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-lfs/git-lfs-ls-files.1.en.html) to list them and then save the output to a file:

```
git lfs ls-files | awk '{print $3}' > lfs-files.txt
```

### Remove large files

> I will use `git lfs ls-files --all --name-only` to get a list of files to delete from all branches and history.
> I want to use filter-repo to delete those but only if they are not
> pointers (1MB is arbitrary, pointers are probably not over 2KB)

A [custom `blob-callback`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS) is not enough, because a blob has data (needed to compute the size), but no filename.
And a `filename_callback` does not have access to the blob and its blob size!

Hence, a `commit_callback`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import git_filter_repo as fr

# Size limit in bytes
SIZE_LIMIT = 2 * 1024  # 2KB

# Set of all files to delete
lfs_files = set(line.strip() for line in open('lfs-files.txt'))

def commit_callback(commit, repo):
    # List to store new file changes
    new_file_changes = []

    for change in commit.file_changes:
        if change.filename.decode() in lfs_files:
            # Get the blob data
            blob_data = change.blob_data

            # If the blob is larger than the size limit, skip it (do not add to new file changes)
            if len(blob_data) > SIZE_LIMIT:
                continue

        # Add the file change (modified or not) to the new file changes
        new_file_changes.append(change)

    # Replace the old file changes with the new file changes
    commit.file_changes = new_file_changes

filtering_options = fr.FilteringOptions.parse_args(['--force', '--replace-refs', 'delete-no-add'])

repo_filter = fr.RepoFilter(filtering_options, commit_callback=commit_callback)
repo_filter.run()
```

Only files that appear in `lfs-files.txt` are processed.
That version of the `commit_callback` function will skip adding file changes to `new_file_changes` if the file is in `lfs_files` and its blob is larger than the size limit. Since `new_file_changes` replaces `commit.file_changes`, this means that these files will not be present in the rewritten commit.

You can run this script with:

```bash
python3 remove_large_files.py
```

Comment: Looks promising. Not sure I understand how to run repo-filter here. You say run it with --path-from-file but also run the clean-files file. What exactly do I need to run when?

Comment: @MickeyCohen Sorry, that option is not relevant. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, I will try. What using is blob.size?

Comment: @MickeyCohen "Delete all the old files before they moved to LFS": the idea is, for files which are already moved to LFS, but only recently, that would clean-up old instances of those same files, still present in the history of the repository. The recent instances are small, the old ones are large. Hence the blob size.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask which unit is the size in

Comment: @MickeyCohen I have actually rewritten the solution. Let me know first if I understood correctly your issue.

Comment: I think this overcomplicates things. Maybe your previous solution was better? I want to run filter-repo with a list of files using --paths-from-file, but have it skip the file if it is smaller than 1MB

Comment: @MickeyCohen OK. I have rewritten the answer to propose a much simpler process.

Comment: I think we lost our path here. This will find ALL files in the current branch that are over 1MB. I'll try to rephrase. I will use git lfs ls-files --all --name-only to get a list of files to delete from all branches and history. I want to use filter-repo to delete those but only if they are not pointers (1MB is arbitrary, pointers are probably not over 2KB)

Comment: @MickeyCohen Well... that is what the previous version was for. It is more complex, though.

Comment: Which of the previous? I got a little lost with the edits. I was hoping for a simpler solution. I have the files to delete, just need to be able to skip pointers

Comment: @MickeyCohen OK, I have rewritten the answer. It still involves a somewhat complex python script. The issue is to have a filter which can access both the filename and its size.

Comment: Getting a lot of errors for the args parsing. I am using python 3.9.13 on Windows. For example: 
File "C:\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1825, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)

Comment: @MickeyCohen Right, creating a `FilteringOptions` manually should be easier. No `parse_args` needed then. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: with this method it is looking for all the other callbacks:
AttributeError: 'FilteringOptions' object has no attribute 'filename_callback'

Comment: the script runs now but it doesn't look like it did anything... The big files that are listed in lfs-files.txt are still there

Comment: @MickeyCohen I suppose the files are still here with their original size?

Comment: yes, that is correct. I checked out an old commit and still see the full size files

Comment: @MickeyCohen OK. I have updated the code to remove the file, instead of etting the blob's data to an empty string and updating the blob id.

Comment: Looks like it didn't do anything because it didn't find the files. The problem was encoding on the lfs-files.txt. I fixed it but now it fails on 'dict' object has no attribute 'get_blob'

Comment: True. I tried using `blob_data`, but the `file_change` object does not have a `blob_data` attribute. You can only check the size of a blob, not its actual contents, when working with the `commit_callback`. The size of a blob can only be checked in the `blob_callback`, but this callback does not provide the file name, which is why it is not helpful for your specific use case. Not sure if there is a straightforward solution here...

Comment: Where can I see the properties/attributes of each object?

Comment: @MickeyCohen Directly in the code source, like https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Anewren%2Fgit-filter-repo+blob_data&type=code

Comment: ok, so to get the blob size I simply ran git cat-file -s in the Python script. It works, returns the size correctly, I change the condition and now that also works fine. But how do I delete the blob? I don't see anything that does that in the updated script

Comment: @MickeyCohen To delete a blob from the commit, you simply do not include the corresponding file change in the new list of file changes (`new_file_changes`). In the script I provided, this is achieved by the line `if len(blob_data) > SIZE_LIMIT: continue`.

In other words, the script is "deleting" the blob by not including its corresponding file change in the new list of file changes for the commit.